# Intellij idea - how to always show method parameter names

Tags: intellij-idea, view, parameters

I have seen in several presentations the feature of always showing the parameter name like is shown in the image.

[image: screenshot]

How can I turn this on please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a feature of the [IntelliJ IDEA Preview 2016.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-3-user-interface), which is parameter hints.

Comment: This feature was moved to Editor > Inlay Hints in 2020.1 and includes some more advanced options

Answer (score 13):

Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show parameter name hints Configure... > Show for non-literals in case of multiple params with the same type

Comment: for TypeScript select the language and then in the `Options` (in the bottom) select `Show name for all arguments`

Answer (score 10):

*Moving [xeno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2342518/xenos)'s comment to answer.*

As of **Intelij Idea 2020.1**, this feature is moved to `Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints` and includes some more advanced options

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure the popup delay when the cursor is inside the parens:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-method-parameter-information.html

Comment: This is what I'm using now. I was looking for a permanent way to show parameter names. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: **`Settings`** > **`Editor`** > **`General`** > **`Code Completion`** >
 **`Show the (documentation | parameters) in ___ ms`**